# Getting error:__init__() takes atleast 4 arguments (4 given) when running on AWS EC2

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras

I am running a convolution neural network to classify MNIST digit dataset on AWS EC2 instances .I am getting the following error log:

```
  File "mnist_cnn.py", line 33, in baseline_model
model.add(Conv2D(32, (5, 5), input_shape=(1, 28, 28), activation='relu'))
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 4 arguments (4 given)
```

I am not able to run completely in my local computer,but for running for only 1 epoch ,the code is running fine but I am unable to figure out the error.Below is the code-snippet where supposedly error is reporting.

```
def baseline_model():
   model=Sequential()
   model.add(Conv2D(32,(5,5),input_shape=(1,28,28),activation='relu'))
   model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
   model.add(Dropout(0.2))
   model.add(Flatten())
   model.add(Dense(128,activation='relu'))
   model.add(Dense(num_classes,activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
   return model
```

Comment: You have 2 positional and 2 keyword arguments; `Conv2D()` has 4 required *positional* arguments, plus more optional keyword arguments.

Comment: Still, the exception doesn't quite seem to fit given the documentation for [`keras.Conv2D`](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#conv2d); is this a different library?

Comment: Or, did you perhaps redefine `Conv2D` or forgot to re-start Python?

Comment: No,I didn't redefine the Conv2D definition

Comment: I'm not that familiar with keras, tbh. I suspect that the version you are using on AWS differs and is using the legacy (pre v2) API; that certainly with [the changes for `Conv2D` described](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/wiki/Keras-2.0-release-notes#convolutional-layers).

Comment: Could you provide us your `keras` version, backend and EC2 instance details?

Comment: keras version=2.1.2,tensorflow backend,and using a gpu of g2.2x large.